# Doubt (or more likely, my misunderstanding) in wikipedia's Pigeonhole principle proof of Dirichlet's approximation theorem

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-explanation

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_approximation_theorem

I will call the following the Lemma of Dirichlet's Approximation theorem:

> For a given irrational α, the inequality
>
> $ 0<\left|\alpha -{\frac {p}{q}}\right|<{\frac {1}{q^{2}}}$ is
> satisfied by infinitely many integers $p$ and $q$.

If I were to summarise wikipedia's proof of this Lemma, it would be this:

Let $\ \alpha\ $ be an irrational number and let $\ n\ $ be an integer. Then there exists $\ p\in\mathbb{Z},\ q \in \{ 1,\ldots, n\}\ $ such that $\ \left\lvert \alpha - \frac{p}{q} \right\rvert < \frac{1}{q^2}.\ $ Here, by $\ q\ $ I mean, $\ q:= j-i.$

But as far as I can see, this *doesn't* prove the Lemma, because for each $\ n,\ q\ $ could be any number between $\ 0\ $ and $\ n\ $, so $\ q\ $ doesn't necessarily tend to infinity as $n$ tends to infinity.

What is wrong with my understanding of the proof?

Edit: When wikipedia says, "Dividing both sides by $j-i$ will result in:

$\left|\alpha -{\frac {m_{j}-m_{i}}{j-i}}\right|<{\frac {1}{(j-i)n}}\leq {\frac {1}{\left(j-i\right)^{2}}}$"

Is it saying that this bit proves the Lemma? Or is the proof in wikipedia just proving the original theorem only?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're right that this step needs explanation. In fact, the version you quoted isn't quite strong enough to prove "infinitely many", as you've noticed. We need to go back to the slightly stronger version:

Let $\alpha$ be irrational and let $n$ be a positive integer. Then there exists integers $p$ and $q\in\{1,\dots,n\}$ such that $\bigl| \alpha-\frac pq \bigr| < \frac1{qn}$.

Note that any such $\frac pq$ automatically satisfies $\bigl| \alpha-\frac pq \bigr| < \frac1{qn} \le \frac1{q^2}$. However, this stronger form shows that we don't just get the same $\frac pq$ over and over: for any fixed $\frac pq$, the quantity $\bigl| \alpha-\frac pq \bigr|$ is positive (this is where we use the fact that $\alpha$ is irrational!), and so it exceeds $\frac1{qn}$ when $n$ is sufficiently large. Thus we must get a new fraction $\frac{p_2}{q_2}$, which can only survive for so long, and so on and so on.